# size reduced or length reduced vector

Tags: vectors

I'm no native English speaker. I want to know if a vector in the HKZ reduced form is called "size reduced" or "length reduced", or can I say both?

Comment: you may speak of a reduced basis  for the lattice. You should not refer to an individual vector as reduced.

Comment: You're not totally right: A basis is HKZ reduced, if it fulfils 2 conditions, see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korkine–Zolotarev_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm). And during the steps of the algorithm for reduction, single vectors are indeed length/size reduced. So your comment does not solve my problem :-)